# Can I use multiple xhtml pages in the one xhtml page and how to access (references to them) those in managed bean class?

Tags: jsf-2

**1)How to include the many xhtml pages in one xhtml page**
**2) how to get the references to them in managed bean class**

Comment: [Facelets](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/facelets-454361.html)

Answer (score 1):

You need to try this

```
 <ui:include src="/page.xhtml">
        <ui:param value="value" name="name" />
 </ui:include>
```

Here, ui:param is used to pass the parameter.

Comment: but how to access the refernces and contents of page.xhtml in managedbean class

Comment: It should be the other way round, you should access the properties and use the functions of managedbean in your xhtml files.